# Base + Offset Addressing Mode

Tags: addressing-mode

I just need an explanation of how base + offset addressing modes work. Having trouble finding a clear-cut answer for this. (I've been working with the LC-3, not sure if that matters). A simple example would also be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe I figured out the answer which is listed below. Thank for those who attempted to answer the question but the answers were not correct (at least in terms of the LC-3 architecture, I'm not sure, maybe base + offset works differently elsewhere). Anyone who is VERY familiar with the LC-3 and is confident in how base + offset addressing works, please review my answer below to see if it is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
MOV EAX,[EBP+8]
MOV EBX,[EBP+12]
```

EBP is the base here (holds the base address) like "00402000" for instance
so the EAX will be loaded with the value in the address [00402000+8] I.e 00402004

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. In the LC-3, the base used is a register. The instruction for the LC-3 opcode looks like this: 0110 010 110 001101    The first four bits is the opcode (an LDR in this case); the next three is the destination register; the next three is the base register; and the last 6 is the offset (in 2's complement). If I am correct (and anyone please correct me if I am wrong), it takes the value of the base register, which is an address, adds the offset to it, and stores the value in the destination register, although I can't seem to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Base + Index addressing mode

2 Registers specify the address of an operand in an instruction.
Add the numerical values stored in those registers to get the complete address of an operand.

```
Ex.
A = 1000
Register A = 1000
Register B = 8

MOV C, [A,B] => C = contents of location A+B
```

There is a flavor to Base + Indexing addressing called the base + Index + displacement

Displacement = immediate value in the instruction that is added to the Base + Index.
thats what you see in your opcode.

instruction = OPCODE + Operand 1 Register Spec + Operand 2's Base Register Spec + Operand 2's Index Register Spec + Immediate value.

imagine a microprocessor with a 8 bit register space.

so a 16 bit operand may have

4 bit for opcode

3 bit for base register
3 bit for index register
6 bit for immediate displacement.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Based on what I have learned in class, I know that you are not adding the two registers together. The destination register is only used to store the calculated value and is not used as an operand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out the answer. I'll post it here in case it helps anyone else who has trouble with this. I found the answer hidden deep in the 100 slide powerpoint that my teacher provided XD

This is what happens when performing an LDR using a base register R6 and destination register R2:

```
MAR<-R6 + IR[5:0]
MDR<-MEM[MAR]
R2<-MDR
```

Lets say R6 = x3000, IR[5:0] = x5, and R2 = 0 (although this value doesn't matter since it will be loaded with another value at the end)

```
MAR<-R6 + IR[5:0]
```

R6 is added to IR[5:0] (which is the offset value in the last six bits of the LDR instruction). The base x3000 (value of R6) has x5 (value of IR[5:0]) added to it, giving us x3005. The MAR (memory address register) now holds x3005.

```
MDR<-MEM[MAR]
```

The value in the MAR (x3005) is loaded into the MDR (memory data register).

```
R2<-MDR
```

The value in the MDR (x3005) is loaded into R2. R2 now holds the value: x3005.

I hope this question helps those new to addressing modes like I am :)

Thank you all.

Comment: "The value in the MAR (x3005) is loaded into the MDR (memory data register)." -- This seems wrong, the `MEM[MAR]` syntax probably means to load a value from the memory address given in the MAR. It does not mean to load the MAR value itself into the MDR.